# Could not find the ColdFusion Component or Interface fuseboxWriter

Tags: coldfusion, fusebox

I'm running ColdFusion 8.1 with FuseBox 5. I originally configured my dynamic virtual hosting in Apache so that my domains pointed to:

```
C:\websites\www.example.com
C:\websites\dev.example.com
C:\websites\legacy.example.com
```

In case we add more domains in the future, I want to have the folder structure as follows:

```
C:\websites\example.com\www
C:\websites\example.com\dev
C:\websites\example.com\legacy
C:\websites\newexample.com\www
C:\websites\newexample.com\admin
```

I get the following error when I use the domain/subdomain structure from ColdFusion:

```
Could not find the ColdFusion Component or Interface fuseboxWriter.

Ensure that the name is correct and that the component or interface exists.
Stack Trace:
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage$NoSuchTemplateException: Could not find the ColdFusion Component or Interface fuseboxWriter.
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.getResolvedFile(TemplateProxyFactory.java:1173)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.getTemplateFileHelper(TemplateProxyFactory.java:1346)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxyFactory.resolveName(TemplateProxyFactory.java:1289)
    at coldfusion.cfc.ComponentProxyFactory.getProxy(ComponentProxyFactory.java:38)
    at coldfusion.runtime.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:65)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.createObjectProxy(CFPage.java:4707)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.CreateObject(CFPage.java:4552)
    at cffuseboxApplication2ecfc339686346$funcCOMPILEREQUEST.runFunction(C:\websites\www.example.com\fb5core\fuseboxApplication.cfc:378)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
    at coldfusion.filter.SilentFilter.invoke(SilentFilter.java:47)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:448)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:308)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2272)
    at cffusebox52ecfm1351851183.runPage(C:\websites\example.com\www\fb5core\fusebox5.cfm:196)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:370)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)
    at cfindex2ecfm588071849.runPage(C:\websites\example.com\www\index.cfm:3)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:370)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)
    at cfApplication2ecfc827193789$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(C:\websites\example.com\www\Application.cfc:36)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:448)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:308)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:74)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:243)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:269)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:86)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:175)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Not sure how much more I can add. Apache is behaving as expected, but something in ColdFusion isn't liking the subfolder setup. I thought that [this solution](http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/solve-the-could-not-find-the-coldfusion-component-issue-71) would work, but the error doesn't appear to be the same as mine. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the paths in the stack trace didn't match, specifically the cffuseboxApplication2ecfc339686346$funcCOMPILEREQUEST.runFunction was pointing to the old folder while all other paths were to the new folder. I performed a fusebox.parseall=true and fusebox.loadclean=true and the site is now operating as expected.